# Rails actions and jbuilder, why they have to be as difficult?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

Rails drive me crazy. I'm trying to respond to with an action with JSON.
My goal is to let be the JSON the only format for a response to a URL.

Let's see some code.

The **Model** is a Devise user, with some added field.
The **Controller** is my `UsersController` that has this action

```
    # /app/controllers/users_controller.rb
    def static
        render json: current_user
    end
```

I got also this jbuilder view

```
    # /app/views/users/static.json.jbuilder
    json.content format_content(@user.content)
    json.author do
        json.name @user.name
        json.email_address @user.email
    end
    if current_user.admin?
        json.someValue "foo"
    end
```

this **View** doesn't do some interesting stuff, but It's just a try.
Anyway I'll never get the `static.json.jbuilder`content. I always get all Devise user's content as a JSON.

Am I doing something wrong? (or better: where I done the epic fail?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway found the solution:

```
    # /config/route.rb
    get 'my-static-json' => 'mycontroller#static', defaults: {format: :json}
```

```
    # /app/controllers/mycontrollers_controller.rb
    def my-static-json
    end
```

```
    # /app/views/mycontrollers/my-static-json.json.jbuolder
    json.content "some static content"
```

this is only an example but gives have all the information that I needed